# Apply category query clause to posts of custom type

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query

I have succeeded at [limiting the posts on my homepage](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#category-parameters) to ones in a *homepage* category that I created by implementing the following in functions.php:

```
function limit_category( $query ) {
  if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
    $query->set( 'category_name', 'homepage' );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'limit_category' );
```

This works fine for posts of type *post*, but I also have some posts of custom type *event* that have the category slug set to *homepage* that are excluded from the homepage.

To display events I am doing this:

```
function include_events( $query ) {
  if( $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home() ) {
      $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'event') );
  }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_events' );
```

Is there a way I can also display event posts on the homepage when they have the homepage category?

Comment: How does the code look where you fetch the events?

Comment: @FabianMossberg I updated my question to include the code you asked for, thanks!

Comment: Using your code, it **works perfectly** for me with your code. If it's not working, then maybe you are not using the **same taxonomy** for `posts` and `events`? Could you also add the code you use to `register_post_type()` event?

Comment: Are event categories the same taxonomy as post categories?

Comment: The event post type is implemented via the [Event Organiser](https://wordpress.org/plugins/event-organiser/) plugin